Как убрать лимит в 30 фпс на телефоне?
Помогаю другу делать небольшой проект на юнити, и тут мы столкнулись с проблемой - а именно то что фпс упирается в потолок 30, он никогда не поднимается выше. На андроид, айфон - без разницы, на ПК все норм, под 300 фпс.
Это не говнокод и фиговая оптимизация - пустая сцена с квадратом посередине выдала ровно 31 фпс. Профайлер ничего такого не показывает.
Пробовали разные методы: Application.tagretframrate = 60, отключение vsync, выбрали в настройках билда устройства (all competitive devices), выключили adaptive performance, и т.д. и т.д. - не проканало.
Я хз что делать, может кто на опыте эту проблему решал? Что ещё можно попробовать предпринять?
